# Kotlin generic out T

Tags: kotlin, generics

I have next code:

```
class Generic<out T: Number>(value: T) {
    var item:  T? = value  // T? marked as compile error: Type parameter  
//T is declared as 'out' but occurs in 'invariant' position in type T?
        private set
```

but this code

```
class Generic<out T: Number>(value: T) {
    val item:  T? = value
```

or this code

```
class Generic<out T: Number>(value: T) {
    private var item:  T? = value
```

is ok. Why?

in first block of code setter is private as in third block.

I try find answer in google, but find nothing